# I want to retrive rows with given input in query (I work with mysql2 package in express )

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, express

```
    static fetchAll(idClass, groupeNumber, adminCreator) {
        return db.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM cohorts WHERE (idClass = ?) AND (groupeNumber = ?  ) AND (adminCreator = ? )",
            [idClass,groupeNumber, adminCreator]
        );
    }
```

if the client(admin) select only filter it according to classId i give the result , and if give me the groupNumber i will give him the query with only the groupNumber column and its value

I Can't fetch all the rows with specfied input i try to make it null (if not given) but it give no value

Comment: can you share your table and the parameters you give to the query and which reult you excpected

Comment: Consider using OR rather than AND might be reasonable for your request.  Then ask your users to request the one they are looking for and enter 0 for the other two id's.